# Invalid Entity | The entity does not exist anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-dots

I am Super new to ECS and DOTS, but wanted to now finally give it a shot. I very quickly ran into a problem where I cannot find anything online.
When I create an Empty Game Object in a Subscene and want to look at it in Game View, I just get the following result:

[image: Unity Error]

So far all I have is an Empty Unity 2022.2.12 URP 3D project with the newest `com.unity.entities.graphics` import in my Scene, a SubScene "EntityScene" with an Empty Game Object.

URP-HighFidelity / Performant-Renderer Settings: Render Path to Forward+

Comment: Ok. Ecs is not fully released. So its still changing and potentially not working. However.  You havent really said anything about what someone can do to recreate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Empty GameObjects, with only Transform and without any childs in SubScene not baking to Entities by default in Entities 1.0. According to your screenshot Inspector is in forced Runtime mode - fully filled orange circle (underscore line means it force selected to this state)

[Your Inspector in force runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i0Yz.png)

You should pick automatic or Mixed\Authoring because empty GameOobject have no Runtime representation (see  my first sentense).

[Should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Eeo.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the Inspector tab to `Runtime` mode:

[image: switch to runtime entities, Unity 2022.2.19, com.unity.entities 1.0.0-pre.65]

> screenshot taken from Unity 2022.2.19 / com.unity.entities 1.0.0-pre.65